# Read Only API KEY

Tags: getstream-io

Can we create a read only API Key? 
We are trying to debug production and want to ensure we don't affect the data. We see how to create a new key but the only option we see for that key is a flag called 'status' which seems to be enable/disable.

Comment: what language are you using? most stream clients have support for readonly token generation

Comment: Hey I am using PHP

Comment: there is no support for readonly token when using the API keys server-side